# I am getting issue while generating identity column value in PostgreSQL. Identity value is scattered across multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I have three tables in my PostgreSQL DB generated via EF Core Migration.
Below is Entity used for migration.

```
public class TableA
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

public class TableB
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int TableAId { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(TableAId))]
        public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }
        
    }
public class TableC
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int TableBId { get; set; }
        public string SomeName { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(TableBId))]
        public virtual TableB TableB { get; set; }
    }
```

Now if I push some data in these tables in Id column of each table values are going as below:

```
Table A
| Id       | Name    |
| ------   | ------- |
| 1        | test1   |
| 8        | test2   |

Table B
| Id       |   TableAId     | Value   |
| -------- | -------------- | ------- |
| 2        |       1        | test13  |
| 3        |       1        | test232 |
| 9        |       8        | test13  |
| 10       |       8        | test232 |

Table C
| Id       |   TableBId     | SomeName |
| -------- | -------------- | -------- |
| 4        |       2        | asdas    |
| 5        |       2        | fsdfs    |
| 6        |       3        | xcvvc    |
| 7        |       3        | sdfsd    |
| 11       |       9        | asdas    |
| 12       |       9        | fsdfs    |
| 13       |       10       | xcvvc    |
| 14       |       10       | sdfsd    |
```

You can see that identity column is getting scattered across each table. I need serial number to be generated in each table for it's Id column.

Note: In each push I am pushing data against Table A > Table B. and after this i have some logic to update finally in Table C.

SQL Generated in Migration Scripts

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "table_a",
                schema: "public",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    id = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
                    name = table.Column<string>(type: "text", maxLength: 100, nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("pk_transaction", x => x.id);
                });

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "table_b",
                schema: "public",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    id = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
                    table_a_id = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false),
                    value = table.Column<string>(type: "text", maxLength: 100, nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("pk_table_b", x => x.id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "fk_table_b_table_a_table_a_id",
                        column: x => x.table_b_id,
                        principalSchema: "public",
                        principalTable: "table_a",
                        principalColumn: "id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "table_c",
                schema: "public",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    id = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
                    table_b_id = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false),
                    some_name = table.Column<string>(type: "text", maxLength: 100, nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("pk_table_c", x => x.id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "fk_table_c_table_b_table_b_id",
                        column: x => x.table_c_id,
                        principalSchema: "public",
                        principalTable: "table_b",
                        principalColumn: "id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
```

Comment: Please show us the actual SQL that is generated. Looks like your obfuscation layer is using a single sequence rather than "real" `identity` columns.

Comment: SQL generated means you are referring to Model snapshot or migration script @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I mean the CREATE TABLE statements.

Comment: Have updated scripts in comments. @a_horse_with_no_name